# C# Post Request Problem Comparing To Python

Tags: python, c#, http

i have problem making post request in c#, i'm trying to make post request using c#

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
{ "email", "hello" },
{ "password", "world" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("myapilink", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

then i get 403 forbidden error code with message [ access denied], so when i try this request in python with the same api, same data, same every thing, using requests library

```
url = 'myapi.com'
data = F"email={email}&password={password}"
req = requests.post(url, data=data)
src = req.text
print(src)
```

i got another source, [ invalid username or password ] and that is the right source [ that should appear to me ] not like c#, so idont know is that c# problem or problem in httpclient in c#, what can i do with this ?

Comment: what's the http return code that C# is giving you? sounds like you are missing some authorization headers in the request

Comment: @d.moncada c# http returns 403 forbidden errors, when i ignore protocol errors i got [ Access Denied, You Dont Have Pemession to access ...... ], in python i got the natural and the usual source [ invalid username or password ]

Comment: @d.moncada i can send you the api and the data if you want to test, cause really i'm going crazy

Comment: Have you checked the rest of the response object in C#? Maybe `req.text` doesn't corrosponse to content. Look at the other properties inb C#. There is a Reason property. What does that say?

Comment: i'm python programmer and i wrote all my code before learning c# in python so i know req.text is getting the source code, here is the link "https://pass-api-v2.canal-plus.com/services/apipublique/login" you can make simple get request, just get request on it with c# and one more get request "NOT POST" in python and tell me what the source you get

Comment: I got this error `{"response":{"errorCode":5,"errorMessage":"Email manquant ou invalide","passId":"","passToken":""}}`. What are the valid form inputs?

Comment: If I pass valid dummy email(e.g. hello@abc.com) I got this error `{"response":{"errorCode":2,"errorMessage":"Portail Id manquant ou inconnu","passId":"","passToken":""}}`

Comment: @Nazim can you give me your code ? , because i got this ""<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;pass&#45;api&#45;v2&#46;canal&#45;plus&#46;com&#47;services&#47;apipublique&#47;login" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;1c9f1702&#46;1591819205&#46;1753041d
</BODY>
</HTML>
"""

Comment: Actually it is your code that I tried :) Here it is if you still want: 
`var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
 { "email", "hello@abc.com" },
 { "password", "world" }
 };

var apiUrl = "https://pass-api-v2.canal-plus.com/services/apipublique/login";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
 var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
 var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
 var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}`

Comment: LOL, in this screenshots https://prnt.sc/sxgfhi you can see the result in c# and the result in python, i dont know what is going on really

Comment: Can you share on your post whole content of class that you are calling api, make sure to include using statements.

Comment: Do you have any authorization? How does the method look like in the api?